# docker daemon: Error initializing network controller

Tags: systemd, docker

Docker CLI returns: `Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?`

`$USER` was added to docker group.

`$systemctl status docker` returns:

```
● docker.service - Docker Application Container Engine
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/docker.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: start-limit-hit) since wo 2019-05-08 12:44:07 CEST; 36min ago
     Docs: https://docs.docker.com
 Main PID: 10460 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
```

`$journal -u docker` returned:

```
Caused by Error starting daemon: Error initializing network controller
```

Comment: no more modification has been implemented? What the output of command journalctl -xe (after systemctl start docker fails)?

Answer (score 1):

After looking through `/var/log/syslog` I have seen `Error starting daemon: Error initializing network controller: invalid CIDR address:` .

The issue was in the unit file `/etc/systemd/system/docker.service` more exactly the **--bip** flag used in `ExecStart=/usr/bin/dockerd`  (which tells the daemon  change the default range of the default docker-bridge) was not good.

PS: useful link for restoring the docker.socket unit-file (version 18.09):

https://github.com/docker/docker-ce/blob/v18.09.0/components/packaging/systemd/docker.service

Comment: Please edit your question as this is not the answer to your question.